# Round Values to Nearest Tens or Hundreds in R?

Tags: r, rounding

I have over 10,000 test scores in my dataframe that were calculated incorrectly. They look like this:

```
Student   Computed Score
1         71.00   
2         55.3489
3         2000.11111
4         1689.66
```

I want to round them to the nearest '10' (Variable 1: 71 = 70, 1689.66 = 1690) and also to the nearest '100' (Variable 2: 71 = 100, 1689.66 = 1700). Because the original values were calculated with 10 point increments and 100 point demarcations. I tried:

`df$Var1<-round(df$Computed_Score, 2)`
but it rounded the decimal places to 2 values (2000.11111 became 2000.11, which isn't helpful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following will do it.

```
x <- scan(text = "
71.00   
55.3489
2000.11111
1689.66")
x

round_to <- function(x, to = 10) round(x/to)*to

round_to(x)
round_to(x, 100)
```

**Edit.**

After the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135763/round-values-to-nearest-tens-or-hundreds-in-r/46135797#comment96996555_46135797) by user ORStudent I have wrote a new function, `roundup_to`.

```
roundup_to <- function(x, to = 10, up = FALSE){
  if(up) round(.Machine$double.eps^0.5 + x/to)*to else round(x/to)*to
}

roundup_to(c(150, 116350), to = 100)
# [1]    200 116400

roundup_to(c(150, 116350), to = 100, up = TRUE)
# [1]    200 116400

roundup_to(c(50, 116250), to = 100)
#[1]      0 116200

roundup_to(c(50, 116250), to = 100, up = TRUE)
#[1]    100 116300
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the function, it seems that the rounding isn't working the way I want it to be when rounding numbers in the middle.  For example, rounding 116250 gives me 116200 instead of 116300. How can I make it round up to the nearest 100?

Comment: How can I make it such that rounding 50 will round up to 100 without affecting rounding a number like 49 to round up to 100 also?

Comment: @ORStudent That is due to IEEE-754 stating that rounding should be to the nearest ***even*** number. Try `round_to(c(150, 116350), to = 100)` and both are rounded up. Try your numbers `round_to(c(50, 116250), to = 100)` and they are rounded down.

Comment: Thanks Rui!! I was able to find a similar solution and just added an if statement inside the function. `round_any <- function(x, accuracy, f){
             if_else(x%%100 >= 50, ceiling(x/ accuracy) * accuracy,
                     round(x/accuracy)*accuracy)}`