# Scale numbers based on the largest value

Tags: r, scale

I have data like this:

```
mydata <- c(365673, 478934, 897464, 254778, 678899)
```

I want to transform *mydata* using unique number. This is how I calculate the unique number:

- Extract the largest number, in this case, it is 897464
- After that we get the unique number is 800000 from 897464
- Then divide the vector with that value

The output that I want is going to be:

```
newdata <- mydata / 800000
newdata
# [1] 0.4570913 0.5986675 1.1218300 0.3184725 0.8486238
```

How do I create the function?

Comment: You could combine `max()` with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135763/round-values-to-nearest-tens-or-hundreds-in-r

Comment: as sample, if we have another data which has 789456 as the largest data, we only extract 700000 from it. And if we have another data which has 457998, we only extract 400000 from it. Sorry i am not explaining it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
scale.nums <- function(v){
  x = max(v)
  pow <- 10^floor(log10(x))
  x <- x %/% pow * pow
  v/x
}
```

For example:

```
> mydata <- c(365673, 478934, 897464, 254778, 678899)
> scale.nums(mydata)
[1] 0.4570913 0.5986675 1.1218300 0.3184725 0.8486238
```

Answer (score 1):

`plyr` has `round_any` function which would be useful here.

```
mydata <- c(365673, 478934, 897464, 254778, 678899)

mydata/max(plyr::round_any(mydata, 100000, floor))
#[1] 0.4570913 0.5986675 1.1218300 0.3184725 0.8486238
```